# Best option between Task, Thread, Multi-Threading, Parallel, Async/await for my project

Tags: c#

As the title says, I'm searching for the most efficient option to use for my program.

Basically my program is doing many I/O tasks ( Opening files, reading them, searching for 4 specific bytes, closing the files )

I have built my program using the normal synchronous method but I feel like the program can work much faster using some of the method listed on the title, which one would be the fastest method to achieve that goal ?

PS : I'm using it on .NET framework instead of .NET core, so please advice me without forgeting that, thanks.

PS2 : I don't want to use any Nuget package too, only the .net framework itself

Comment: Try them out. You can gauge the pros and cons yourself. We are not the developers for your application, so we can't say what's "right" for it.

Comment: IO-bound tasks = async/await. You generally don't want to fire background threads for that (which is what `Task.Run()` and the `Parallel` class do) unless you have a good reason. If needed, you can run parallel asynchronous operations too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use **Task** combined with **async**/**await**.

Comment: And why that over Parallel, or threads? What about the OP's code makes this approprate?

Comment: @gunr2171 "Basically my program is doing many I/O tasks"

Comment: Also Tasks are a single API that allow you to do async method calls, and create long-running background processes (like Thread), or do many Tasks in parallel, like Parallel.ForeEach.

Comment: I fear such general advice is not the intention of this opinion based question.

Comment: It is mvc or webform? If webform it will be a little hard to implement the async await for the ui(.aspx). Otherwise no issue.

Comment: @gunr2171, Rezo answer is the proper one, your advice about telling how should people learn programming is not, thanks anyways.